# Finder is using over 100% of CPU and makes entire system slow

Tags: macos, finder, memory

Every since upgrading to Lion my system has started to slow down, big time.  I realized that the Finder was using over 100% of the CPU, even when I am really not doing anything with it.  I restart it, and after a bit, it is back up to over 100%, making everything else crawl.

I have done a disk repair and permissions repair as suggested elsewhere but that does not seem to help.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: are you using any network file shares?

Comment: I do, but I connect to them, do what I need, then disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what it was a permissions issue.  Running Fix Permissions in Disk Util fixed the issue.  Strange.  But, found one other place online talking about this and how it worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

Please attach a screenshot of the Activity Monitor window during this issue, or describe which process in specific. There are a number of these related to functions with Finder or the system that may or may not be connected.